# Adding a UIView to an existing UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I'm trying to incorporate a control into an existing `ViewController`, but the new view isn't drawing where I want it to. In the code below, I think I've isolated where my problem lies, but I don't know how to fix it.

I have a `UIView` called [StepperView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stepperview) that I'm trying to add to an existing `UIViewController`. In the past when I've added a view to a `UIViewController`, I've done it *entirely programmatically* **OR** *entirely with AutoLayout*.

In this instance, my storyboard is configured already in AutoLayout and I'd like to keep it that way. I'm having trouble getting `StepperView` to display inside the `UIView` object I've laid out in Interface Builder. I've added a `UIView` object to my storyboard, added constraints, and created an `IBOutlet` in `MyViewController.m`. I also added an import statement for `StepperView` to `MyViewController.m` as follows:

```
#import "StepperView.h"
// a bunch of properties
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet StepperView *stepperView;
```

in my `viewDidLoad` of `MyViewController.m`, I'm instantiating the `stepperView` as follows:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.stepperView];
// this is the method I'm calling to instantiate stepperView
[self.stepperView drawStepperInView:self.stepperView];
```

I'd like to configure `StepperView` to fill the `UIView` object I've set up in storyboard. Instead, it's displaying outside the area of the screen I've set up for it in Interface Builder.

This is `drawStepperInView` from `StepperView.m`:

```
- (void)drawStepperInView:(UIView *)containerView {

    if (_numberCurrent <= 0) {

        _numberCompleted = 0;
        _numberCurrent = 1;

    } else if (_numberCurrent > _numberTotalStep) {

        _numberCompleted = _numberTotalStep - 1;
        _numberCurrent = _numberTotalStep + 1;

    } else {
        _numberCompleted = _numberCurrent - 1;
    }
    // ** I think my problem lives here...
    CGFloat _startPointX = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - STEPPER_WIDTH) / 2;
    if (_startX) {
        _startPointX = _startX;
    }

    // ** and here.
    CGFloat _startPointY = 100.0f;
    if (_startY) {
        _startPointY = _startY;
    }

    _stepperPipeBG = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_startPointX, _startPointY, STEPPER_WIDTH, STEPPER_HEIGHT)];
    _stepperPipeBG.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(225.0f/256.0f) green:(225.0f/256.0f) blue:(225.0f/256.0f) alpha:1.0f];
    [containerView addSubview:_stepperPipeBG];


    CGFloat _stepperPipeFrontWidth = ((STEPPER_WIDTH / (_numberTotalStep - 1)) * _numberCompleted);
    _stepperPipeFront = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 4.0f, _stepperPipeFrontWidth, (STEPPER_HEIGHT - 8.0f))];
    _stepperPipeFront.backgroundColor = COMPLETED_COLOR;
    _stepperPipeFront.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
    _stepperPipeFront.layer.borderColor = COMPLETED_BORDER_COLOR.CGColor;
    [_stepperPipeBG addSubview:_stepperPipeFront];

    for (int i=1; i<=_numberTotalStep; i++) {
        int status = MARK_UNTOUCHED;
        if (i < _numberCurrent) {
            status = MARK_COMPLETED;
        } else if (i == _numberCurrent) {
            status = MARK_CURRENT;
        } else {
            status = MARK_UNTOUCHED;
        }
        [self drawStepperMarkInView:_stepperPipeBG withNumber:i withStatus:status];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `MyViewController`, I pinned the `UIView` object that I added for `stepperView` to the left and right edges of the screen. I also changed `_startPointY` in `StepperView.m`'s `drawInStepperView:containerView` method to this:

```
CGFloat _startPointY = 0.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something here but have you tried simply saying:

```
   stepperView.frame = containerViewFrame
```

Also, if you are using AutoLayout then you will want to override the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method so that AutoLayout can render the view container first.

I would remove the code from viewDidLoad and add:

```
 -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.stepperView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:self.stepperView];
    [self.stepperView drawStepperInView:self.stepperView];
```

Comment: Where would you put that line?